# Eliminate some records from sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have written the following query from various tables :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 0 AS IID, 
       pd.IID AS PurchaseOrerDetailsId, 
       i.[Description] AS ITEM, 
       '' AS BatchNo, 
       s.[Description] AS Unit,
       '' AS MfgDt, 
       0 AS QtyReceived, 
       '' AS ExpiryDate, 
       '' AS PackSize, 
       0 AS QtyOrdered, 
       0 AS MRP, 
       0 AS PTR,
       0 AS PTS, 
       0 AS PurchaseRate, 
       0 AS CGST, 
       0 AS SGST, 
       0 AS IGST, 
       0 AS DiscPer, 
       0 AS DiscVal, 
       0 AS PurchaseValue, 
       0 AS CGSTAmt,
       0 AS SGSTAmt, 
       i.IID AS ItemId
FROM   PurchaseOrderDetails pd
LEFT JOIN StockDetails sd ON pd.ItemId = sd.ItemId
INNER JOIN Items i ON i.IID = pd.ItemId
INNER JOIN Strings s ON s.IID = i.Unit
WHERE pd.PurchaseOrderId = 1
```

I am getting the following result:

[image]

Now I want to eliminate first two records (PurchaseOrerDetailsId is 1 and 2).
Any clue.

Thanks
Partha

Comment: Change "WHERE pd.PurchaseOrderId = 1" to "WHERE pd.PurchaseOrderId = 1 AND PurchaseOrderDetailsID > 2"

Comment: Add a `NOT IN` clause to your `WHERE`, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there is more to it.  But based on what you supplied:

```
 and pd.IID > 2
```

You don't use `StockDetails sd`.  That left join is a waste.

All those hard coded values are not needed for the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number() as [rn] inside a CTE, after that you can select [rn] > 2.

Comment: That seems like mad overkill